# вопрос по fileOutputStream.write методу. Почему в данном случае метод .write() fileOutputStrem'a записывает char а не байты в текстовый файл?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

```
  while ((data = zipInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                        fileOutputStream.write(data);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: язык программирования укажите, пожалуйста, в виде метки, нажав [edit]

Comment: Мне кажется вы не совсем верно понимаете запись байтов/символов. Любой символ это представление определенной последовательности байт. Ваш текстовый редактор просто читает эту последовательноть и декодирует ее как символ.

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что он записывает не байты, а символы? Напишите например простой цикл с инкрементом целого от 0 до 10 и записью этого целого типа `stream.write(i)` и посмотрите файл любым шестнадцатеричным редактором -- там будут байты от 0 до 10, простым текстовым редактором увидите "крокозябры".